# Persist a tree with Hibernate OGM and MongoDB, the collections that represent the tree are incorrect

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

My goal is to persist a tree on a store MongoDB using Hibernate OGM (4.1.1 Final) with JPA annotations.
I wrote two classes called Node and NodeLink: the first defines the nodes while the second the links between them.

the Node class:

```
@Entity
public class Node {

private Set<NodeLink> children;

private String id;
private String name;

public Node() {
    children = new HashSet<>();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Type(type = "objectid")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@OneToMany( mappedBy="source" )
public Set<NodeLink> getChildren() {
    return children;
}
void setChildren(Set<NodeLink> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
```

}

the NodeLink class:

```
@Entity
public class NodeLink {

private String id;

private Node source;
private Node target;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Type(type = "objectid")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne
public Node getSource() {
    return source;
}
void setSource(Node source) {
    this.source = source;
}
public void assignSource(Node source) {
    setSource(source);
    source.getChildren().add(this);
}

@ManyToOne
public Node getTarget() {
    return target;
}
void setTarget(Node target) {
    this.target = target;
}
public void assignTarget(Node target) {
    setTarget(target);
}
```

}

The code that creates the classes and persist them is as it follows:

```
    EntityTransaction transaction1 = manager.getTransaction();
    transaction1.begin();

    Node root = new Node();
    root.setName("root");
    Node children1 = new Node();
    children1.setName("children1");
    Node children2 = new Node();
    children2.setName("children2");

    NodeLink nl1 = new NodeLink();
    nl1.assignSource(root);
    nl1.assignTarget(children1);

    NodeLink nl2 = new NodeLink();
    nl2.assignSource(root);
    nl2.assignTarget(children2);

    manager.persist(root);
    manager.persist(children1);
    manager.persist(children2);
    manager.persist(nl1);
    manager.persist(nl2);

    transaction1.commit();
```

[What is persisted in MongoDB is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mADR.png)

As can be seen on the image, the 'root' node is persisted correctly, with the correct references to children. Instead, the 'children1' and 'children2' nodes each have one reference to a NodeLink object, even if the original object does not have them. So my question is: this behavior is due to a bug in Hibernate OGM or MongoDB? Otherwise there is an error in my code?

Comment: Yes, it seems a bug. I'm Investingating

Comment: Thank for your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have found a bug.
I've created an issue and sent a pull request: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-1198

You could try to test the pull request or wait until the next release.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'll try soon in the next few days

Comment: We just released 5.0.3.Final, it will contain the fix for this issue

Comment: Thanks Simone, I've mentioned your contribution here: http://in.relation.to/2016/11/08/hibernate-ogm-with-hotrod-support/

Comment: Thanks for the mention